# Visual Studio IIS works fine but when hosted in IIS 7 scripts gets the wrong URL?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reference, include

**Hi,**

I have a ASP.NET MVC site where I use the following links in the MasterPage

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../Scripts/jquery.cascadingDropDown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js"></script>
```

This works fine when running from the built in IIS in Visual Studio 2010 and at the host(IIS7). But when deploying it in my own IIS7 under Default Web Site \ MySite the scripts will get a path like this :

```
http://localhost/Scripts/jquery.cascadingDropDown.js
```

Instead of :

```
http://localhost/myPage/Scripts/jquery.cascadingDropDown.js
```

Why is this working in VS IIS and my Host IIS but not on my local computer IIS?

The webpage runes fine besides this.

Comment: why not use @Scripts.Render() / @Url.Content / src="~/Script/etc"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I repeat 2 absolutely fundamental rules in ASP.NET MVC:

1. **Never hardcode urls as you did**.
2. **Always use Url helpers when dealing with urls in an ASP.NET MVC application.**

I have been repeating this gazillion of times in gazillion of similar questions and still I see people hardcoding.

So if you are using Razor:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.cascadingDropDown.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js")"></script>
```

And if you are using WebForms view engine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.cascadingDropDown.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js") %>"></script>
```

And hey, if you are using ASP.NET MVC 4 (Razor 2.0), there's a neat trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.cascadingDropDown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js"></script>
```

Notice the `~/`? WebPages 2.0 automatically apply an `Url.Content` on it at runtime to produce the correct url.

Comment: The #1 rule is to test early often with IIS :) AS Darin mentions, with razor2/MVC 4 you no longer need to use @Url.Content,  you need to use ~ and not hardcoded relative paths.