# MVC3 jQuery getJSON doesnt issue a call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, getjson

I am trying to make ajax work using getJSON() call.
When I navigate to /Home/GetWeather, I get Json data back in the browser.
However the jQuery call is not working. Any ideas?
When I put a breakpoint on alert("Hello"), it never hit.
In firebug I dont see any ajax call. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Button1").click(function() {
        $.getJSON("/Home/GetWeather", null, function(data) {
            alert("Hello");
        });
    });
});​
```

**Controller code**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetWeather()
    {
        List<Weather> weather = new List<Weather>();

        // populate weather with data

        return Json(weather, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#Button1").click(function () {
                $.getJSON("/Home/GetWeather", null, function (data) { //I hit breakpoint here, but in firebug I dont see any call, nothing
                    alert("Hello"); // Breakpoint here doesnt hit :(
                });
            });

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" name="Button1" value="Get Weather" />
    <div id="Weather"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Any reason why the solution I found was removed ???**

Comment: Corrent path to your controller? Might be something like `../Home/GetWeather`. Also, you can remove `null` from your call

Comment: Check that you don't have any problems with Same Origin Policy. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538215/cross-domain-scripting-issues-jsonp

Comment: @CharlieKilian. He's sending data to the controller, how can he viiolate the same origin policy?

Comment: do you get any errors in the firebug or chrome dev tools? have you included the jquery.js? is the `#Button1` anchor tag?

Comment: also inspect the full request in console... data sent & returned, status etc

Comment: It is correct, it returns the JSON data as expected.
The call to controller DOES NOT fire, that's the problem.

Comment: public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult GetWeather()
        {
            List<Weather> weather = new List<Weather>();

            // populate weather with data

            return Json(weather, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

Comment: breakpoint hits $.getJSON in javascript code, but doesnt actually make the call :(

Comment: Please show us your view. Most important how the button looks like.

Comment: Try this: `alert($)` if the result it `undefined` then you didn't included jQuery right.

Comment: Now you update your question...? the first time you really should write an answer, you edit your question... Please do it.

Comment: Why are you using such an old jQuery version (1.7.2 is the recent version). You also shouldn't include the `-vsdoc` version in a way where it's actually used in the browser. It's **only** for visual studio's intellisense.

Comment: That's what I did, I updated the first post with the answer.
But it was removed by moderator.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you're trying to call it cross domain. Having the code run out of the domain of the site. Before I had the html file call the json running from localhost and it does return nothing. But put that html into the same place, call it from localhost and you will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

- Don't hard code URL with `Asp.Net-MVC` use `Url.Action`
- Remove the `null` parameter. Why do you need to send `null` to the controller? just omit it.

The code to get the route right:

```
@Url.Action("GetWeather", "Home")
```

Inside the script:

```
$("#Button1").click(function () {
    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetWeather", "Home")", function (data) {
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't make any difference if there is null or no null.
I dont need Url.Action, I am using jQuery
All within the same MVC app.

Comment: @Sigourney_Weaver. Right, so why keeping it?! Three dots

Comment: As I said, it doesn change anything, ok, I remove it if you want, same problem.

Comment: As I said, when navigating /Home/GetWeather in browser, I get JSON data back.
No error in firebug.

Comment: Actually, as I said I dont see the call being made in firebug.
I have no idea why, it should absolutely simple, exactly as in the tutorial.

Comment: @Sigourney_Weaver. 1. Did you use the `@UrlAction`? 2. Do you have errors in your console? 3. I got the feeling you don't have `"#Button1"` element. Try this: `$("#Button1").click(function() { alert('foo')});`

Comment: It doesn't change anything now, but does make it much easier to manage if you start moving stuff around later on.

Comment: What are you talking about @justinb138? Who did you refer to?

Comment: Url.Action vs hard-coding a route

Comment: Have you checked your script reference to verify that your jquery.js file is reachable?

Comment: @justinb138. You should use `@Sigourney_Weaver` to make him get your comments. Now I'm the only one see them... and writing them on the question should be a better place. btw, if he didn't include jQuery he would have got an error long time ago.

Comment: Not sure I understand how this comments thing works... :)
Of course all the references are fine

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you cancel the default action of the button if it is a submit button or an anchor by returning false:

```
$("#Button1").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("/Home/GetWeather", null, function(data) {
        alert("Hello");
    });

    return false; // <!-- cancel the default action of the button
});
```

Also as `@gdoron` said in his answer, never hardcode urls like this. Always use url helpers to generate them.

---

UPDATE:

Now that you have shown your view, I can see that you have hardcoded the url to your scripts:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You should [never do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11154110/29407). You should always use url helpers:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also you should learn to use a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug which makes detecting those errors a peace of cake. If you have used FireBug you would have seen the 404 errors when requesting those scripts.

Comment: But he's mentioning he doesn't see the request in FireBug, if that was the issue, he should have seen it, doesn't it master?

Comment: He is not seeing it because he gets redirected and there's no time for the AJAX request to even start. Unfortunately since the OP hasn't shown his view we could only be guessing if this is the case or not.

Comment: Maybe, I'm waiting to see he's view to be sure. If that's the issue, he should have told us he's redirecting with the anchor... :(

Comment: Nothing is redirected, it's not a submit button.

Comment: Then the code should work and if it doesn't FureBug will tell you why.

Comment: @Sigourney_Weaver. Is it an anchor?

Comment: What anchor? I dont nee any anchor, I am using jQuery, forget about MVC, I could use jQuery from HTML page.

Comment: Hi Darin, but if he doesn't have jQuery referenced, he should get errors when using `$`, so... I don't know. :(

Comment: That's right. Then the only thing left is JSON serialization problems of the `Weather` class that he is using. Are you able to see the generated JSON when you directly navigate to `/Home/GetWeather`?

Comment: I know how to use firebug :)
Hardcoding <script> is not a problem.
I am not talking abut coding style, I am talking about getJSON not working.
Besides using @Url.Content() you dont get jQuery intellisence.

Comment: If you know how to use FireBug, what do you see in the Console or the Net tab when you click on the button? Can you see the request being sent?

Comment: @Sigourney_Weaver. You little bit confused by jQuery <> Razor, but never mind, Darin, he's saying he doesn't even see the request in FireBug, not just the response. X-Files...

Comment: Yes, as I said before, in Firebug, I dont see any request when clicking the button, it hits the break point on getJSON, but no request in Firebug. That's why I am asking the question, because it seems that getJSON function has a bug.

Comment: @Sigourney_Weaver. Try sending with **.ajax** Code: `$.ajax({
  url: "@Url.Action('GetWeather', 'Home')",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(){alert('YES');}, 
  error: function(){alert('ERROR!');}
});` It's equals to `getJSON`.

Comment: $.getJSON has no bug at all, I can assure you. Could you show how your `Weather` class looks like?

Comment: gordon, your code throw runtime exception:
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Compiler Error Message: CS1012: Too many characters in character literal

Source Error:


Line 16:             $("#Button1").click(function () {
Line 17: 
Line 18:                 $.ajax({ url: "@Url.Action('GetWeather', 'Home')", dataType: 'json', success: function () { alert('YES'); }, error: function () { alert('ERROR!'); } });
Line 19:

Comment: I dont need to use any of razor helpers,
My page could be just HTML

Comment: @Sigourney_Weaver. Of course my bad. It should be `$.ajax({ url: '@Url.Action("GetWeather", "Home")', dataType: 'json', success: function(){alert('YES');}, error: function(){alert('ERROR!');} });` But you should have got this error long time a ago. Note, make sure to add `@gdoron` to your comments or else I won't see them.

Comment: I found the solution, posted it, but someone removed it :(
I don't understand why :(

Comment: Sorry guys, but it seems that you dont have an idea what you're talking about. Why would you want to see the Weather class, Darin?
Did you understand the problem I explained? LOL

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem - and it was not with the code! 
But problem resolution was removed by moderator for unknown reason :(
Well, good luck, when you have the same problem and dont know what to do, call the moderator :)

Comment: @Sigourney_Weaver, I hope everything goes well now with your code. You might also like to read the FAQ about how to use this site.